# Is there a way to host Axis2 service within PHP/WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, apache-axis

I am new to web services and I am learning to create web service on Axis 2 framework. I created a couple of simple (HelloWorld type) web services. I want to host these services on my Hostgator account, currently having a wordpress installation on it. I am not able to find a link between Php based framework and Axis 2. Is there a way to do that?

P.S:  I dont want to write SOAP based web service in PHP yet.

Comment: @toTheOneWhoDownVoted: If you could just tell us why you down voted, that would be helpful. Instead of just down voting because you did not like it.

Comment: Do your hosting service allow you to deploy your Java web services or any other Java application? How are you currently running your web services right now?

Comment: @Alfabravo: I researched more and found that Hostgator doesnot allow me to run Java application on my plan. It uses an httpd server, which seems like cannot host a web service. I think the answer to my question is that we cannot host it on httpd server. However, still hopeful if there is something that can help me without purchasing a new account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look, as you have found yourself, hosting an HTTP server (with HTML/PHP,JS files and a PHP interpreter engine) is different from hosting a Java web application (like your web services). You need a different hosting solution where you can deploy a web container/web server with your Web services application and there's no way your current hosting alone will do the trick.